# JS files doesn't load on apache2

Tags: javascript, html, css, apache2

I have a website that on my localhost machine works fines, but on the apache FTP server (`/var/www/html/test`) doesn't load only the JS files. The question is do I need to store the JS files in another folder. Now they are under the test folder `/var/www/html/test/pricing-tables/pricing-with/js`

Comment: The question is way broad to answer. Add more details, please.

Comment: That's all it is. It doesn't load the JS files. I have a JS file that switch when you click the radio button it swaps between two <ul> but it doesn't work.

Comment: post your js and html please

Comment: html -> http://pastebin.com/DR8piCnd
js-> http://pastebin.com/r5QYBaBP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with permissions. Thanks for the help